# Do I need to manually disconnect my Google Drive credentials from Google Colab?

Tags: python, security, google-colaboratory

I am new to using Google Colab and I am currently mounting data from Google Drive like this:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Do I need to be worried about potential security issues? Do I need to manually clear out sessions?

Or does Google Colab automatically know to scrub credentials when we terminate a remote connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your session is terminated, your Google Drive will be automatically dismounted from the remote virtual machine. Moreover, when you run the same notebook again, you have to remount the drive and provide access again.

So, there are no security issues with your credentials.